# RoleArn is not supported for target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to pass a role that contains KMS permissions to roleArn of my [target](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events/client/put_targets.html) that is associated with a rule and it doesn't work

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutTargets operation: RoleArn is not supported for target arn:aws:sqs:sa-east-1:1234:my-queue-name.",
```

I wanted it to work to not give the problem of kms denied and be sent to DLQ

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass a [service-linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html) to the SQS service which it does not support.

> A role that a service assumes to perform actions on your behalf is
> called a [service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role). When a role serves a specialized purpose
> for a service, it is categorized as a [service role for EC2
> instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role-ec2) (for example), or a [service-linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-linked-role).

[image]

Sources:-[AWS services that work with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html), [Creating a role to delegate permissions to an AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html),

Hope it helps.